# Can a variable be set in a function in Python?

Tags: python, function

I was trying to ensure in a Python program that the user-entered lower and upper bounds of a range to not intersect each other and also that they do not become less than 0. However, I could not get the variable to be set to a value that is defined by the user while a function was running.

The following was the code:

```
def boundcheck(n, minimum):
    while n < minimum:
        n = int(input(f"Enter a number above {minimum - 1}: "))

l = int(input("Enter lower bound in range: "))
boundcheck(l, 0)
print(l)

u = int(input("\nEnter upper bound in range: "))
boundcheck(u, l)
print(u)
```

For example, if at the beginning, `l` is defined as `-5` by the user, the function `boundcheck()` returns an `input()` statement asking for the user for a number greater than -1. However, in place of `n`, `l` is not being updated to the re-entered number by the user. Can you change a variable's value in a function?

Comment: You can by using `global` (or `nonlocal`) keyword, but you should avoid it if possible. Preferred way would be to accept a value using function parameter and return it from a function, assigning return value back to variable.

Comment: @matszwecja `global` doesn't work when the variable you'll be changing is itself variable (i.e. `l` in the first case and `u` in the second).

Comment: I think that you should use return statement and only return the 'n' from inside the function when it is valid and does not violate the rule. Sadly I can't post answer to SO, because it is marked as duplicate. But here is link to my solution anyways.
https://imgur.com/a/erebEsG